# Libgdx, JSON: Json.tojson(object) keeps returning {}

Tags: java, json, string, libgdx

I looked over most of the googable tutorials online for using Json in Libgdx, which seems pretty straight forward. But, for some reason the json.toJson() keeps returning a two celled array, the first containing { and the second containing a }.
My code is very simple:

```
public class GameConfig {  
    public int screenWidth;  
    public int screenHeight;  

    public GameConfig() { 
        screenWidth = 800; 
        screenHeight = 600;  
    }  
}
```

Then

```
String configAsText = json.toJson(zzz);//configAsText.value equals [0] = { and [1] = }  
String configAsText = json.toJson(config, GameConfig.class);//nor this one
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you instantiate the json object?

Comment: Do you understand what JSON is? It is not a "two celled array", but the `String` `{}` which represents an empty object in JSON.

Comment: Christian Cederquist<- like this Json json = new Json();

Comment: I think I have read enough about JSON to understand what it basically is, and what it is used for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following code. I use it like this and in most cases I don't need any custom serializer because of the internal reflection which libgdx uses to serialize.

```
Json json = new Json();

json.setTypeName(null);
json.setUsePrototypes(false);
json.setIgnoreUnknownFields(true);
json.setOutputType(OutputType.json);

json.toJson(config, GameConfig.class);
```

Comment: @coffeenet If you can convert it to JSON without a special serializer, you should be able to also convert it back.

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't convert it back (with the above code, nor without). The code you provided converts it perfectly toJson(). But, that same converted string, cannot be converted back using fromJson(). It keeps throwing an exception. dermetfanTut: Unable to parse existing config data file
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Class cannot be created (non-static member class): com.dermetfan.tut.gameengine.GameConfig$ScreenResolution

Comment: When I removed all the inner classes, and tested with just one int variable inside the converted data, it worked :s Still cant tell what is OK and what is NOT OK in the json rules.